# find and copy command not working in bash

Tags: linux, bash, find, copy

This line works in the terminal, but not in a bash script:

`cd /home/me/Downloads/Data/$currentYear/$currentMonth/$currentDay/`
`find . -name '*.wav' -exec cp {} $tempfolder \;`

I'm trying to copy all the WAVE files from all the sub-directories to a temporary folder

Comment: You need to escape `\{`

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the script and knowing what you see and what you expect – "does not work" doesn't give us any hints. And without context, there is no way of telling if any of the variables are set etc.

Comment: @stark That's not usually necessary.

Comment: when I echo the line it says 

find . -name '*.wav' -exec cp {} home me data

which is weird because it should say find . -name '*.wav' -exec cp {} /home/me/data

Comment: Double quote `"$tempfolder"`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell that doesn't work.

Comment: Please see Benjamin's comment above. Please also run `echo "$tempfolder"` to check its content.

Comment: @stark : You don't escape if you just hav `{}`. Try it out: `echo {}`

Comment: @DevSenGoku : Provided that the content of `tempfolder` is reasonable, your command is fine. You already correctly tried to diagnose by doing an `echo`. This output means that the content of the variable `tempfolder` is not what you expect. I would check it by inserting a `xxd <<<"$tempfolder"`, just before the `find` command.

Comment: Add `sed -eux` at the beginning of your Bash script in order to debug it.

Comment: did you try: `find . -name '*.wav' -exec cp "{}" "$tempfolder" \;` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell $tempfolder is nothing but _/home/me/Desktop/songs/_

Comment: @OliverGaida I tried this, doesn't work.

Comment: @BenjaminW all the variables are set. I'm just trying to copy all my downloads that come in the format of **/home/me/Downloads/songs/Year/Month/Day/Hour/Minute/** to a temporary folder on the desktop. $tempfolder is nothing but **/home/me/Desktop/songs/**

Comment: So, I solved it. Turns out, that the `cd /home/me/Downloads/Data/$currentYear/$currentMonth/$currentDay/` was not actually changing the directory for the `find .` to work. The script was trying to find the files in its own directory. Once i wrote `find "$absolutePath" -name '*.wav' -exec cp {} "$tempfolder" \;` it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved it. Turns out, that the
`cd /home/me/Downloads/Data/$currentYear/$currentMonth/$currentDay/`
was not actually changing the directory for the
`find .`
to work. **The script was trying to find the files in its own directory.** Once i wrote `find "$absolutePath" -name '*.wav' -exec cp {} "$tempfolder" \;` it worked